# how define driver in python for an open net page

Tags: python, android, html, selenium, driver

I have an open net tab on my app and now I want to work by selenium to do several works.How can I define its driver?I know how to define a driver and open a webpage but I don't know this one. Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally,

you can take its html code by

> driver.page_source